# What are all the types of NSNotifications?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

Do you know of a comprehensive list of all possible NSNotifications? Please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A notification name can be any arbitrary string, so the number of possible notifications is effectively unlimited. The documentation for most classes will list the notifications they are guaranteed to send at given times.

Answer (score 34):

That's not a very helpful answer, IMHO - lots of notifications are hard to find, and some are undocumented.

When I need to see what's *actually* there, I use something like this:

```
// inside your Application Delegate / main method / similar:

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onNotification:) name:nil object:nil];

-(void)onNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSLog(@"Notification name is %@ sent by %@",[notification name], [[notification object] description] );
}
```

Comment: I agree! Gonna use this for sure

Comment: Indeed, this is the better answer. Super useful trick, thanks.